# JavaScript: redefine the object linked to a function parameter

Tags: javascript, overwrite

I'm new to JavaScript and I've been stuck on this for a moment. I never expected this to be a problem but well here I am.
Here's my code:

```
a = alert
b = console.log

function reset(func, cb){

    //Here I'm just redefining "func" which is a local argument
    //The question is how can I redefine the function this argument is referencing?

    func = function(){
        cb("gud")
    }
}

reset(a, alert)
reset(b, console.log)

a("alert: bad")
b("console.log: bad")
```

I want both alert and console.log to be overwritten by my new function.
The should be equal to alert("gud") and console.log("gud"). I tried to eval it, it worked for alert but since console.log's name is only "log", this method couldn't work. Any idea?

Comment: This isn't possible. Function arguments are passed by value, assigning to the local variable has no effect on the caller's variable.

Comment: It's not possible to do this. This smells a lot like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-xy-problem) what are you actually trying to solve that requires redefining functions?

Comment: @VLAZ I just want to dynamically overwrite functions

Comment: @HellProtection but *why*? What you want is not possible. Except extreme hacks that will require more effort to pull off than it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be simple if you return the result.

```js
let a = alert
let b = console.log

function reset(cb){

    //Here i'm just redefining "func" wich is a local argument
    //The question is how can I redefine the function this argument is referencing?

    return function(){
        cb("gud")
    }
}

a = reset(alert)
b = reset(console.log)

a("alert: bad")
b("console.log: bad")
```

Comment: Yeah this is what i'll go for. From the responses I got this seems impossible to do my way. It doesn't fully solve the question but so far it's the best I could do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this is what you're actually trying to do:

```js
function reset(func){
    // return a new function which overwrites what is passed in
    return function(){
        func("gud")
    }
}

var a = reset(alert)
var b = reset(console.log)

a("alert: bad")
b("console.log: bad")
```